# Simple Linux benchmarking tool

Tags: linux, performance

I seem to remember Windows has (had) some tool that lets you measure the performance of your PC.

It's a bit simplistic but you get a simple number (e.g. 4.2 out of 5) to tell you how performant your PC is.

Is there anything similar for Linux?

I've tried `sysbench` and I'm really not interested in having to interpret a load of gibberish. E.g.

```
sysbench --test=cpu run
WARNING: the --test option is deprecated. You can pass a script name or path on the command line without any options.
sysbench 1.0.20 (using system LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3)

Running the test with following options:
Number of threads: 1
Initializing random number generator from current time


Prime numbers limit: 10000

Initializing worker threads...

Threads started!

CPU speed:
    events per second:  1076.94

General statistics:
    total time:                          10.0001s
    total number of events:              10771

Latency (ms):
         min:                                    0.69
         avg:                                    0.93
         max:                                   14.34
         95th percentile:                        1.25
         sum:                                 9994.25

Threads fairness:
    events (avg/stddev):           10771.0000/0.00
    execution time (avg/stddev):   9.9942/0.00
```

Comment: What units is the Windows program measuring?

Comment: Insofar as this is about benchmarking your Linux system as a whole and not about benchmarking software you're developing, it's quite off topic here. (Even if it were the latter question, it would still be a tool recommendation request and off topic for that reason; not not even being about software development in the first place makes it doubly so).

Comment: (By the way, for benchmarking software you're developing, first choice is language/runtime-aware tools -- specialized JVM benchmarks for Java-based tools etc -- and then a mix of sampling profilers or instrumentation-based profilers, depending on how much it's acceptable for the act of measurement to change the results; oprofile is one of my favorites, but like any tool written to provide enough details to guide engineering decisions, it's going to rewrite interpretation of _ahem_ "a load of gibberish")

Comment: @stark, ...the Windows tool in question (if it's the one I'm thinking of) doesn't have any units at all; it's a composite score, with GPU factoring in a certain amount, CPU factoring in a certain amount, IO factoring in a certain amount, and a bunch of opaque, undocumented magic Microsoft came up with combining those factors to generate a final score.